# Calculation of real root values of $x$ in $\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{4x-1}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Calculation of x real root values from $ y(x)=\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{4x-1} $

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Here domain of equation is  $\displaystyle x\geq 1$. So squaring both sides we get

$\displaystyle (x+1)+(x-1)-2\sqrt{x^2-1}=(4x-1)$.

$\displaystyle (1-2x)^2=4(x^2-1)\Rightarrow 1+4x^2-4x=4x^2-4\Rightarrow x=\frac{5}{4}.$

But when we put $\displaystyle x = \frac{5}{4}\;,$ We get $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=2\Rightarrow 1=2.$(False.)

So we get no solution.

My Question is : Can we solve above question by using comparision of expressions?

Something like $\sqrt{x+1}<\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4x-1}\; \forall x\geq 1?$

If that way possible, please help me solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, proving inequality for all real $x$ amounts to disproving equality for all real $x$.

Comment: Vincenzo Oliva, would you like to explain me, Thanks

Comment: When squaring or cubing, extra roots are added and may be, as in your case, none of them is a solution.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That  was not what the OP is asking for. He did use the method of squaring and crosschecking all soultions found; he is asking for an *alternative* approach.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. I understood that and he did a good work as well as he asked a good question.

Comment: @juantheron I've added an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $x\ge1$ we have $$\sqrt{4x-1}\ge \sqrt {3x} $$
and $$\sqrt{x+1}\le \sqrt {2x}$$
hence
$$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}\le \sqrt{2x}<\sqrt{3x}\le\sqrt{4x-1} $$

Comment: Well done! (+1).

Comment: SImple and nice way to do it ! When your answer appeared, I was about to propose something stupid since too complex. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Also, for $x\ge1$ $$\sqrt{4x-1}+\sqrt{x-1}\ge\sqrt{4x-1+x-1}=\sqrt{5x-2}>\sqrt{2x}\ge\sqrt{x+1}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, isolating $ \sqrt{4x-1}$ and then multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}$ makes it easier to conclude the LHS is smaller than the RHS: $$\require\cancel \cancel{x}+1-\cancel{x}+1=2<\sqrt{4x-1}\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}\right).\tag{$\star$}$$

Once we check $(\star)$ holds for $x=1$ we are done, since clearly its RHS is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ge1$,

$$l(x):=\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}=\dfrac2{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}}\le\sqrt2$$ and

$$r(x):=\sqrt{4x-1}\ge\sqrt3.$$